# What is the best way to reuse selenium element locators?

Tags: java, selenium

As we know, Selenium TCs make use of locators (like `By.xpath`, `By.id`, etc.) to identify a DOM elements. However, as the code base increases, it becomes difficult to manage these locators.

What is the best way to reuse/maintain these locators?

Comment: isn't the question a bit too generic? can you narrow down the scope of it a bit, and to provide some code snippets so we are speaking about something more specific? thanks.

Comment: Questions asking for opinions are not a good fit for SO so this question will probably be closed soon. Having said that, I would strongly recommend you look into the page object model. It's very easy to use and consume and helps greatly with organization. I find properties files messy.

Comment: Property files are much better for things that configure differently from system to system, like database services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [page object pattern](http://www.assertselenium.com/automation-design-practices/page-object-pattern/) is the best current way to manage locators.

- Object Oriented approach
- Organized by page
- Can be organized in directories
- Supports making additional methods as needed for manipulated interaction

Comment: I use the page object model on a daily basis and I find that it is by far the best way to manage locators, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways but i personally like .properties files in java, where you define all your selectors:
Create a properties file lets call it selectors.properties and seperate it by sections:

```
#page 1
userNameSelector= input.loginName
passwordSelector= input.password
submitSelector= button.submit
#page 2
...
```

Then read the properties file

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
try {
properties.load(new FileInputStream("path/filename"));
} catch (IOException e) {
  ...
}
```

and afterwards in your testcases:

```
fineElement(by.cssSelector(properties.getProperty(userNameSelector));
```

and so on

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

As with most everything in life, I would argue that there is no one "best" way.  So much depends on the structure of your code, the volume of locators, your development processes, how you define the locators (Selector or string?), etc.

For instance, at my current job, where we have a relatively small GUI surface to automate, we decided to keep the locators close to the code.  As a result, they reside in the object class where they are used.  That makes maintenance a bit easier in this situation.  I have done it differently at other companies.